# Как сделать кнопку активной только в воскресенье

Tags: php, javascript

Вот сам скрипт.

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">
    <input style="width: 200px; margin: 5px 0 0 0" class="subm" type='submit' name='submit' value=' Подать заявку ' />
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Нужно чтоб кнопка была видна всегда, но при этом начинала обработку(работу) только в воскресенья. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Поправте формат - [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/681339/edit)

Comment: @АндрейАндрей, добавь больше кода в вопрос. Лучше всего сделай [mcve] - где ключевые слова **минимальный** и **воспроизводимый**

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sunday = document.querySelector('.sunday'); // выбираем кому назначить обработку
const day = new Date().getDay(); // получам номер дня недели

if(day === 0) { // тут номер дня недели 
  sunday.disabled = false;
}else {
  sunday.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td  align="right">
    <input  style="width: 200px; margin: 5px 0 0 0" class="subm sunday" type='submit ' name='submit' value=' Подать заявку ' />
    
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: И, дополнительно, в php делать такую проверку: `date('w') == 0`. JS ограничения можно обойти.

Comment: По JS, у меня `getDay()` для воскресенья возвращается `0`. Не скажу за все браузеры - смотрел FF и GC. Возможно, в других или в определённых версиях и возвращается `7`. Поэтому, предлагаю делать такую проверку: `if(day % 7 === 0) {`.

Comment: @Vitaly [getDay](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date.prototype.getday) уже возвращает `day % 7` поэтому дополнительно делать то же самое нет смысла.

Comment: @bad4iz Спасибо большое,но к сожалению ничего не получается кнопка все ровно дает нажиматься. Браузер Google Chrome.Прописал код вот так:                                                                                       
 <script>
 const sunday = document.querySelector('.sunday'); // выбираем кому назначить обработку
const day = new Date().getDay(); // получам номер дня недели

if(day === 7) { // тут номер дня недели 
  sunday.disabled = false;
}else {
  sunday.disabled = true;
}
</script>

Comment: Далее вот так <tr><td></td><td align="right"><input style="width: 200px; margin: 5px 0 0 0" class="subm sunday" type='submit' name='submit' value=' Подать заявку ' /><br></td></tr>

Comment: Вот ссылка http://dropmefiles.com/fntMK на исходник,может я что-то не правильно делаю...

Comment: @АндрейАндрей, прочитай комментарии под ответом: `getDay` возвращает значение `0..6` - поэтому условие `day === 7` всегда false

Comment: @АндрейАндрей для того, чтобы форма не сабмитилась, можно поступить следующим образом: если кнопка отправки формы не вызывает дополнительных функций, то форме добавить событие `onsubmit="return [ПРОВЕРКА_АКТИВНОСТИ_КНОПКИ]"`; если кнопка отправки формы вызывает функцию, то подобную проверку можно сделать там.

Comment: @Grundy куда бы я не ставил скрипт и даже прописывал 0, серовно не работает.Кнопка даже делает обработку ,а должна ничего не делать, и вроде есть в скрипте sunday.disabled но ничего не работает.Работает только в ручную? если я сам пропишу disabled='true' Подать заявку' /><br></td></tr>В чем может еще проблема быть?Там листинг большой,но какая разница где я прописываю скрипт..

Comment: @Vitaly вызывает по мимо это много чего.Чуть выше есть листинг. Я конечно понимаю разбератся в нем не охота, но если что строчка 187.

Comment: @АндрейАндрей у тебя в сторчке 187 нет класса `sunday` мой скрипт *видно же* делает активным только тот класс который имеет класс `sunday`

Comment: @АндрейАндрей да и сколько у тебя таких кнопок на странице? если одна то все должно работать. Если же несколько то надо просто обработать массив к кассом `sunday ` если что я покажу как

Comment: @bad4iz Там был исходник,потом я поправил как вы сказали, добавил ваш скрипт и класс.В скрипте указан "0",класс прописан:class="subm sunday". Кнопка у меня 1-на на этой страничке. Вот код который сделал после вас http://dropmefiles.com/6XRCq .Строчка 170 это скрипт,а строчка 199 это кнопка.

Comment: скрипт вы ниже подключаете? скинь код

Comment: @bad4iz и спасибо вам что помогаете!!!

Comment: @bad4iz скрипт я подключаю чуть выше кнопки

Comment: пока еще не смотрел файл но видно сразу что есть ошибка .
скрипт js выбирает дом элемент а его еще браузер не подгрузил.
попробуйте за кнопкой разместить свой скрипт. Да и как правило скрипты обычно размещают перед самим закрывающим тегом `</body>` что бы dom успел загрузиться а потом только идет в дело js

Comment: @bad4iz Ура-Ура! получилось работает!!!!!СПАСИБО)))))Я сделал после кнопки после закртыия. Я даже не знал что js есть разница где находится скрипту.Спасибо вам большое))У меня конечно теперь есть еще вопросы,но мучать вас не хочу больше)))

Comment: @АндрейАндрей если по этой теме и небольшой то задавай или сделай новый вопрос и скинь сылку можно сюда

Comment: @bad4iz тема другая.. создал новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684161/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5